# Microsoft Word textbox border disappears when clicked on

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a table with 3 columns and as many rows until it overflows to the next page. Then, I insert a list in a row of the table in the next page. Next, I added a textbox. I then change the wrapping to **In Line with Text**.

The issue is, when I click the textbox, the border **disappears and moves to the top-left** of the page. The text in the textbox still remain at the same place.

See the GIF below for a visual explanation (said issue occurs at end of GIF):

[image]

**Workaround**

Re-select the Wrap Text to In Line with Text or restart Word. This reinstates the textbox border but the problem still happens when you click on the textbox.

**Other notes**

I'm using Microsoft Word for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11029.20045) 32-bit and my OS is Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: Your text box does not appear to be anchored in the cell. That may or may not have something to do with the behavior. Change where it is anchored and make sure the border is always visible by changing the format.

Comment: @RichMichaels I created the textbox inside the table, if that's what you meant by anchoring. I have also updated the GIF with how I created the table and textbox from start to end. Do try it out and let me know if you also faced the same problem. It seems to happen only when we use **In Line with Text** wrapping for the textbox

Comment: No, anchoring is a non-visual reference point in the document where the text box "exists".  It is used to define how the text box behaves in relation to the rest of the document and can even take up no space.  The object is then positioned relative to the anchor so it moves with the rest of the document. 
See https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008229_Understanding_Object_Anchors.html

Comment: @tudor ok... but all the options (including anchoring) under the Layout>Position tab are greyed out if using **In Line with Text** wrapping... so I guess you can't anchor it anyway... maybe it is automatically anchored for you, which makes sense from the wording of that wrapping.